# Difference between doLayout() and doComponentLayout() in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

As the title says, what is the difference between calling `doLayout()` and `doComponentLayout()` for a component in Sencha Touch? I tried having a look at the documentation, but it did not clearly explain this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two are actually quite different. `doLayout` is a container method used to set the sizes of child components within the container. `doComponentLayout` is a component method used to size the elements (typically) that make up that component.

`doLayout` does not explicitly propagate to child containers; but since layouts are setSize driven, any changes in size to child components will trigger the appropriate ComponentLayout -> ContainerLayout.